# Google App Script Form not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using google app script to create a form for uploading file. This is my Code.gs file:

```
var SPREADSHEET_FILE_ID = '1oQn6OLMzys8tVk1FLriOAmpzFJNazLRP-SwM7--eA58';
var folderId = "0B9TN_-yt-h0WZ0dnWndGWkw3UkE";

function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');

  // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
};
```

And I am using all other codes almost similar to the url https://script.google.com/d/125dG42eB9lM4SPq64p0dpR2CBH4ohfHiqu9TvFNM8s4Ra7pt-7kHXoTM/edit?usp=sharing. 
I am getting the following error.

> 3402363213-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: "doc" is not defined.

[image]
Can anyone please help why this error is coming and how to prevent this. No for is not being submitted. It is hanged after I click the button of submission.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem started when you added these values, I think you need to recheck them.

```
var SPREADSHEET_FILE_ID = '1oQn6OLMzys8tVk1FLriOAmpzFJNazLRP-SwM7--eA58';
var folderId = "0B9TN_-yt-h0WZ0dnWndGWkw3UkE";
```

`var SPREADSHEET_FILE_ID` is expecting an spreadsheet ID like "`1386834576`" where as you provided "`1oQn6OLMzys8tVk1FLriOAmpzFJNazLRP-SwM7--eA58`", which is wrong. I think you got that from something like "`https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1BqxyEG8RhtlM3MNuSbln6C1L1GLl3axdiSEijcwB5gY/edit`" that's why it's asking you "doc" is not defined.